# How to block an email which did not sent a direct message to you?

Tags: gmail, spam

I'm sorry I am not sure the proper wording to explain this issue.

I have constantly been receiving emails such as the one I attached (at the bottom). Altough I am able to block emails from "Order_Shipment", several email addresses remain sending messages to PennyV1@aol.com as well as PennyYA@aol.com, which is redirected to me. I could not find a way to block these two emails. I get several emails daily through them, and I would like it to stop.
Things I tried:

1 - Searched in the google settings, and couldn't find anywhere how to specifically block an email by typing the address.

2 - The three vertical dots on the left allows me to block the specific email from Order_Shipment, this does not solve the problem as the real problem is blokcing PennyV1 and PennyYA.

3 - Sent an email to PennyV1@aol.com as well as PennyYA@aol.com in the hope they would sent me an email back so I can block them. My message got bounced back saying these emails don't exist.

I do not know how my email entered this email grouplist [image: Spam example]

Answer (score 1):

You could try blocking their domain:

[image]

Like clicking "Block Quora Digest" in my case.

Option two would be two create a filter: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccreate-a-filter

Comment: This will block Order_Shipment. Just today I also got similar emails with names "You're_Approved", "Clinical_trials", so forth. This pennyV1@aol.com is the one I believe I must block, but it won't show in the boxes that you sent a print of. Example https://paste.pics/0bdeaec4ad35455dc6351c73e0f42129

Comment: Have you tried creating a filter for messages that are sent to PennyV1@aol.com? If that doesn't work, I'm not sure how to help you. Hopefully gmail will find a pattern and start blocking those messages.

Comment: This worked. I wasn't aware of this filtering feature. Thanks!